# Using jQuery, how to open/close a div in between content?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How could I open a div just just after a `<form>` and close it before the `</form>` using JQuery?

I tried like this..

```
$("#Form1").prepend("<div id='mb_wrapper'>");
```

but then the `<div>` is opened and closed just after the `<form>` like this..

```
<form id="Form1">
    <div id="mb_wrapper"></div>
--form contents goes here
</form>
```

actually, I want like to achieve that:

```
<form id="Form1">
    <div id="mb_wrapper">
*--form goes here contents--*

</div>
</form>
```

How should I write my code?

Comment: lol, misuse of prepend and append, when you're prepending like that it auto closes the div  immidiatly after its added the html

Comment: @SpYk3HH I See, actually I don't know that, ok let me try it on another way.

Comment: You reminded me of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721164/stop-jquery-correcting-html). Read it and you'll understand that `$("#Form1").append("</div>");` makes no sense.

Comment: @thirtydot, you're correct, I'm not sure about the prepend/append selectors now I learned, although my problem was fixed by a simple selector said AlienWebguy that is 'wrapInner' thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#Form1').wrapInner('<div id="mb_wrapper" />');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/WSamg/

Comment: lol wow, i been using jquery for a long minute and pretty pro at it but somehow missed this function, thanx for the heads up, thats nice

Answer (score 0):

```
var contents = $("#Form1").children().detach();
var div = $('<div />').attr('id', 'mb_wrapper').append(contents);
$("#Form1").empty().append(div);
```

Out of curiosity, why not just change your markup?

Comment: Its for center align the contents inside the form, the mb_wrapper id will do that..

Comment: Okay... but editing your markup *once* fixes the form permanently, rather than using jQuery (and processor cycles) every time this needs done. Also, why not just add the `id="mb_wrapper"` to the `form` element?

Comment: pete, I've tried that but some reasons it won't work. dont know why.. instead I came with this idea.